# Solr ALPHABETICAL RANGE QUERY

Tags: solr, alphabetical

I am trying implement an alphabetical range to perform a query in Solr 3.3.
The user wants to fetch a list of restaurants which names start with (for example) A to G. Tried with "frange" function but it includes every field that has the letter. I want to get the restaurants wich names START with a specific letter.

Something like: "Get all restaurants from A to G": (A* and G*) but not (*a* and *g*).

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `name:[a TO h]` where `name` field is not tokenized. If required, create a separate copy of the field for this.

If you try this on a tokenized field, then it will match all names which contain a word which ***starts*** with one of these letters. Also, you need to 'increment' the last letter of the range. If it is `z`, then replace it with `*`. For example, if the user is looking for `w` to `z` then the query should be `name:[w TO *]`.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `name:[a TO g]` ?

Comment: I'm pretty sure this won't do what the OP wants.

Comment: Yes I've tried, but it doesn't retrieve the results that start with those letters. Instead, it matches every single "name" containing those letters