# How does range query work when there is special characters in the query term?

Tags: solr, lucene

Referred [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8883419/solr-alphabetical-range-query), [this](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/the-standard-query-parser.html#TheStandardQueryParser-RangeSearches)

**Query:**

`rang:[16-03-08 TO 16-04-08]`

I am using `standard tokenizer and lower case filter` for name field. Field Type is `text`.

Since it is standard Tokenizer, `16-03-08` will be tokenized to `16`, `03`, `08` Similary the other one `16`, `04`, `08`

How does the range query work on this?

Comment: You have tokenized the data....do not tokenized the data and try...try by applying string type to the field..it its date type you can apply date fieldtype to it

Comment: Looking at the fields it seems it the date fields...if it date fields please refer https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/working-with-dates.html

Comment: It'll be unpredictable at best - i.e. giving results that you do not expect - and in many cases, probably no results at all.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the sample data I have used to illustrate.

```
{
    "id":"1",
    "RangeField":"16-03-08",
    "DateField" :"2018-11-21"
},
{
    "id":"2",
    "RangeField":"16-04-08",
    "DateField" :"2019-01-11"
},
{
    "id":"3",
    "RangeField":"16-06-08",
    "DateField" :"2019-04-19"
},
{
    "id":"4",
    "RangeField":"16-07-08",
    "DateField" :"2019-08-24"
},
{
    "id":"5",
    "RangeField":"16-08-08",
    "DateField" :"2019-11-29"
}
```

Here are the fields defined in the `schema.xml`

```
<field name="RangeField" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="false"/>
<field name="DateField" type="date" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="false"/>
```

Here is the query executed

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/TestDemo4/select?fl=RangeField,DateField&q=RangeField:[16-03-08%20TO%2016-06-08]
```

Please refer the screenshot for the response.

[image]

Here is the second query on date field.

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/TestDemo4/select?fl=RangeField,DateField&q=DateField:[2018-11-08T00:00:00Z%20TO%202019-08-30T23:59:59Z]
```

Please refer the screenshot for the response.

[image]

If you have the numberic data then instead of string use the int as fieldtype so it will not create any issue at the sorting time.